# MS Excel 2010 - Auto populate Based on information on another sheet

Tags: excel

The goal is to create a formatted balance Sheet based on information (data dump) off of the database.

[Download Excel File](http://www.4shared.com/file/2lkXx4Cu/sample_statements.html)

There are 2 worsheets

Work Sheet 1: Raw Data Sheet

```
Column A Column B

Grp 1     Name 1
Grp 1     Name 2
Grp 2     Name 45
```

I need to populate Work Sheet 2 as

```
Column A  Column B 
Grp 1
            Name 1
            Name 2

Total Grp 1: 

Grp 2
            Name 45 
Total Grp 2
```

This needs to be automated such that if a new Row is added to the Raw Data Sheet (e.g Grp 1, Name 76) it should be reflected on the other worksheet.

I'm not an Excel Pro (macros, vba etc...) - any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to automatically update the second sheet when sheet 1 is updated. Not because it's impossible but the ways to achieve this in Excel tend to be flaky and make the program unresponsive. Consider adding a button that you would press to update sheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about just making a Pivot Table?

Create a pivot table with Row Labels Column A and Column B, and Values with whatever fields you want to aggregate. It won't update automatically but you just have to hit the "Refresh" button in the PivotTable Options ribbon to update the data.

Comment: Thanks - that's the road I took - let's see how far I go :) -